# Don't show chapter in toc

Tags: table-of-contents

I use the classic thesis style from [latextemplates](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/classicthesis-typographic-thesis) to make my internship memoir. So I've the classic document section: part, chapter, section, subsection, ...

I use the part chapter of it to make an introduction and so I use the same title for the Chapter. In the table of contents I've two entry that just follow themselves with the same name:

> Title part
>
> 1 Title part

What I wanna do is delete the chapter entry but still continue to have a numerotation of it to be use in the document.

Is it possible?

EDIT:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\input{classicthesis-config} %it's on the latextemplates folder

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\part{first part}
\chapter{first part} % should be not present in toc but numbered
\section{a section}
\section{another one}

\part{second part}
\chapter{second part} % should be not present in toc but numbered
\section{foo}
\seciont{foo foo}


\end{document}
```

Comment: As always: Please provide an MWE showing this behaviour. It is not clear where you are using a part or a chapter. A bit confusing. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: my bad for the MWE, I was thinking that was clear but in fact no. I've add it

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: seems to be yes. Didn't find it by searching sorry for the duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that the `classicthesis-config` is not needed in order to show my approach.

The idea is to redefine the toc depth locally. The toc depth tells latex, how many levels you want to display in your table of contents. In a `report` (or `scrreprt` class, the level has to be set on `-1` in order to hide a chapter. In front of your next `section` or alike, you redefine the depth back to what ever you like. `3` was just a guess.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{scrreprt}
%\input{classicthesis-config} % hope this is not needed for my example
\usepackage{blindtext}    

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{first part}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
\chapter{first part} % should be not present in toc but numbered
\blindtext
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
\section{a section}
\blindtext
\section{another one}
\blindtext
\part{second part}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
\chapter{second part} % should be not present in toc but numbered
\blindtext
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
\section{foo}
\blindtext
\section{foo foo}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This work perfectly and avoid the `\input{classicthesis-config}` is not a problem

Comment: Glad to hear that.